# Is there a way to tee mysql special commands with exclamation mark?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I'm on the mysql command line and execute a shortcut to list OS data, such as the following:

```
tee /tmp/output.log
mysql> \! hostname
dbatestserver
mysql> \! date
Mon Feb 13 18:00:52 EST 2023
```

it does not save the resulting "dbatestserver" and date value in my output file. I'm more worried about hostname output, as there are multiple options to pull the date.

Is there an option or a switch that will allow me to have this output go to my log?

I log into mysql with following options:

```
mysql -p -v -c --show-warnings -A
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this with the `tee` functionality within the MySQL client.

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/client/mysql.cc#L4126-L4133

```
  /*
    The output of the shell command does not
    get directed to the pager or the outfile
  */
  if (system(shell_cmd) == -1) {
```

You can do it *outside* the MySQL client.

```
% mysql -e "\\! date" | tee err
Mon Feb 13 19:30:39 PST 2023

% more err
Mon Feb 13 19:30:39 PST 2023
```